# Solving for an $x$ in matrices, with condition $AB=BA$

Tags: matrices

I'm just starting to learn about matrices, and during one exercise I got a question to which I have no answer; Due to the fact that I haven't learned it yet...

The question is as follows:

> Let $A = \left[\begin{matrix}1&x\\2&3\end{matrix}\right]$ and $B = \left[\begin{matrix}1&1\\1&2\end{matrix}\right]$
>
> If $AB = BA$ what is the value of $x$?

I have absolutely no clue of how to solve this effectively.

One way I managed to get a (correct) result was through series of inequalities, which both looked, and was ugly to handle...

If anyone could concisely explain how one would go about solving this, and similar problems, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: actually multiply the two matrices as given and set them equal to see what happens

Comment: Inequalities?! That sounds much harder, and potentially off-track...

Comment: @rschwieb Indeed, it was; Thus the creation of this question thread! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this question, you just need to know how to multiply square matrices, and you need to know what it means for matrices to be equal.

Here is an effective way to solve the problem:

1. Compute $AB$.
2. Compute $BA$.
3. Compare the matrices for equality (means their corresponding entries must match.)

Comment: So there is no way around computing both product combinations of the matrices?

Comment: You seem excessively worried about avoiding a relatively tiny amount of work :) You can put your work in the comments here and I'll tell you if you're still OK or not.

Comment: Yeah, this answers my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Let's go ahead and compute the product of those two matrices, which you seem to be apprehensive about doing.  Taking $A$ and $B$ as you've defined them, we have
$$
AB = \begin{bmatrix}
1+x & 1+2x\\
5 & 8
\end{bmatrix}\\
BA = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & x+3 \\
5 & x+6
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Now, using the fact that all of these entries should match, find $x$.  Notice that what we have isn't a complicated system of equations, but a set of consistent and redundant equations for $x$, any of which can be solved.

Now, if you wanted to solve this efficiently (since you happen to know that there is a solution), you could have just computed the upper-left entries of the matrix product and compared those; computing the rest of the matrix product only serves to confirm the answer you get.